# Prototype select class contained in a div

Tags: class, html, prototypejs, css-selectors

I would like to use the following function **only on the "a" elements contained in the div "myDiv"**.

This is the code I have been using so far:

```
$$('a[class="active"]').each(function(element) {
      element.removeClassName("active");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that two ways:

1) Look up `myDiv` and then use [`Element#select`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/select/):

```
$('myDiv').select('a[class="active"]').each(...);
```

or

2) Use an ID selector with a descendant selector with `$$`:

```
$$('#myDiv a[class="active"]).each(...);
```

If you want only *direct* children (not descendants), you could use a child selector (note the `>`):

```
$$('#myDiv > a[class="active"]).each(...);
```

---

Off-topic #1: The usual way to write `a[class="active"]` in a selector would be `a.active`, e.g., "`$('myDiv').select('a.active').each(...);`".

Off-topic #2: You might also look at the [`invoke`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/prototype/invoke/) function, which is for calling the same function on each item in an Enumerable object (so for instance, "`$('myDiv').select('a[class="active"]').invoke('removeClassName', 'active');`"). `invoke` is nice, short, and expressive, but it's slower than doing it yourself as you did. (It only matters when you get into thousands of elements, though.)